# Unable to send an email to the correct user using PowerShell after remote installation is complete

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that utilizes try catch to install software on a remote computer using PowerShell.

The script tries to install the software and if successfully is supposed to send an email to the user advising of completion. All works as I had expected except for the send email section.

I am using the following simple snippet to carry out the sending of the email:

```powershell
$username = "someone@example.com"
$password = "*****"
$sstr = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $sstr
$body = "Update installed successfully"
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$name = $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
Send-MailMessage -To $name, "someone@example.com" -From "someone@example.com" -Subject 'Test message' -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -smtpserver smtp.office365.com -usessl -Credential $cred -Port 587
```

However, as I am running the script as myself (for elevated privilege's) on the remote computer the following part of the script is returning my email address and not the end users and therefore sending the email to myself and not the end user:

```powershell
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
$name = $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
```

Example

```powershell
echo $name
myemail@example.com
```

Any suggestions on how I can return the name of the user I am installing the software on instead of my own?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by _"name of the user I am installing the software on"_, you mean the console user on the remote sytem, then try the `UserName` property from a query to `Win32_ComputerSystem` WMI class: `(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`.

Comment: Apologies, it's actually the AD email address of the logged in console user I am looking for but I can work with this. I can append the domain name to the end of the ```UserName``` and that will supply the email address I am looking for. Thank you!!